# CakePhp authentication with specific user role id

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I've got some problems with CakePhp authentication component.
I've create user with empty username, after that i've change his username directly in database. 
But i still cannot login. Also - nobody with same role_id cannot login. 
A've try var_dump it in app_controller, but $this->Auth->User() is empty.
can you give me advice, in what direction should i go?
I'm using cakephp 1.3

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to login with Authenticate component you should use `$this->Auth->login()` because as I read in this [article](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-AuthComponent.html) the user method is a method for getting current user in sessions, not for login. check that article about Auth component.